# Why do we need mainQueueConcurrencyType in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm a newbie in Core Data and get confused about which concurrency queue type I should specify when creating a NSManagedObjectContext. When do we want to use mainQueueConcurrencyType? Here is how Apple documented:

> Private queue
> (NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType):
> The context creates and manages a private queue.
>
> Main queue
> (NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType): The
> context is associated with the main queue, and as such is tied into
> the application’s event loop, but it is otherwise similar to a private
> queue-based context. You use this queue type for contexts linked to
> controllers and UI objects that are required to be used only on the
> main thread.

I know there is a NSFetchedResultsController that can be associated with a UITableView, but I'm not going to use this controller. Can anyone show me an example of how to use mainQueueConcurrencyType?

From my understanding, assume we have a NSManagedObject subclass called CoreDataDesk and it will be used to draw desk objects on screen like this:

```
class CoreDataDesk: NSManagedObject {
    var color: UIColor?
}
class DeskView: UIView {
    // Create a MOC with mainQueueConcurrencyType first.
    // Then fetch a bunch of CoreDataDesk objects to initialize DeskView objects.
    required init(desk: CoreDataDesk) {
        self.backgroundColor = desk.color
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    }
}
```

Is this a correct example of using main concurrency type context to fetch CoreDataDesk objects and draws UI with them? If so, I think we can do fetch CoreDataDesk with private concurrency type context instead, then we initialize another Desk class(which is not NSManagedObject subclass) with CoreDataDesk still in background thread. Finally we switch back to main thread and use Desk to initialize DeskView as follows:

```
class CoreDataDesk: NSManagedObject {
    var color: UIColor?
}
class Desk {
    var color: UIColor?
    init(coreDataDesk: CoreDataDesk) {
        color = coreDataDesk.color
    }
}
func fetchCoreDataDesk() {
    // Create a MOC with privateQueueConcurrencyType first.
    // Then fetch a bunch of CoreDataDesk objects.
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // convert each CoreDataDesk to Desk
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything with private queue concurrency. You can also pretty much do everything with main queue concurrency. They're different options for different needs and programming styles. Your approach would work but it's not the only way.

Managed objects are not thread safe, so if you fetch one, you need to use it on the same thread where it was fetched. If you plan to use it on the main queue-- for example to update the UI-- then it must be fetched on the main queue. Main queue concurrency supports this. This is true whether or not you use `NSFetchedResultsController`.

If you want to write a bunch of code to convert between managed objects and non-managed objects or structs (your `Desk` and `CoreDataDesk`, for example), that might not be necessary-- if your non-managed objects are thread safe. Core Data doesn't require you to do that, so it's up to you to decide whether to accept the extra complexity in order to avoid main queue concurrency.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using main queue concurrency because the main thread may be blocked if there's a lot of data need to be fetched from Core Data. In this case, is there any better solution?